# CNet router - no field for private port

Tags: router, nat, port-forwarding, firmware

I'm trying to configure port forwarding on my CNet router for a locally hosted HTTP server. The model number of my router is CQR-981 and the firmware version is 1.0.43.

The problem is that there's no field to enter the private port of the HTTP server (the local port). According to the manual there should be one.

Here's a picture of the manual:

[image: As you can see, there's a private port field.]

Here's a screenshot of my router page for port forwarding (with no field for private port):

[image]

Is there some way I can circumvent this problem. Perhaps manually make an HTTP request to the HTTP server on the router to update the table with the private port number, or perhaps update my firmware to solve this problem.

Comment: Your router, at least from this screen, only supports port forwarding where only the destination IP address is changed.

Comment: Well my HTTP server is running on port 80 and even when I enter the public port range 80-80 and the correct local IP address to port forward it doesn't work. When I browse to my public IP adress on port 80 it tells me that the connection was closed by the foreign host.

Comment: It's not going to work for you since you're on the inside. Port forwarding only works from the outside to the inside (you need hairpin NAT to make local outside addresses work from the inside). Also, many routers can't forward port 80 unless you move their web-based GUI to a different port first.

Comment: So that means that if I ask a friend of mine to connect to my site then he'll be able to see it, but I won't?

Comment: If you have things working correctly, yes. Though, again, some routers can't forward the same port their web-based GUI is operating on. But if you moved that to another port, it should work.

Comment: Ah, alright. I port forwarded my HTTP server. Would you mind checking if it opens for you? http://210.89.52.204/

Comment: You can test it yourself through `tor` or a proxy site like `hidemyass.com`. I get no replies from that IP though, perhaps because of firewalling or perhaps because of something wrong in your configuration. (100% confirm that that IP address is assigned to the device you configured port forwarding on. Check its IP configuration page.)